# Anchoring cameras to Hardie Plank and brick

Tags: electrical, brick, cables, soffit

I am trying to anchor several cameras to Hardie Plank board and to brick. I wanted to ask before I make a mistake in the install.

For both Hardie and brick, I was going to use #10 anchors and screws but they are too wide for the camera mounting plate so I am going to use #8.

1. The Hardie board is roughly 5/16 thick. Would these [anchors](https://www.homedepot.com/p/8-10-White-and-10-12-Blue-Ribbed-Plastic-Anchor-Pack-with-Screws-202-Piece-802474/204273415) be ok?
2. Is there anything I need to know before I drill into brick?

I'm not very knowledgeable about construction and running cables but I am reading a bit and trying to learn.

[image]

Here is picture of what it will look like.

[image]

Just wanted to run this by guys who have done this before for advice and guidance.

Comment: OT side note: Interesting how they advertise that pkg of anchors as "202 pieces". _Technically_, the screw and anchor _are_ 2 individual pieces, but only have enough anchors to fill up 100 holes, not 200 as one might presume from reading "202 pieces". Gotta love the marketing department!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a strength perspective you're fine. I think anchors in brick are usually rated for something silly like 400 pounds. Make sure you're drilling into brick and not the mortar.

Since this is for outdoor use I would at least consider galvanized or stainless steel screws so that you don't have rust streaks later on. It's probably fine under the eave but you'll kick yourself if you get rust streaks in a few years.

When drilling make sure to use a hammer drill.

Make sure your cables are tucked tight into the corner of that eave. UV light, aka the Sun, is rubber's and plastic's worst enemy.

Comment: People like to drill into the mortar between the bricks because it's easy, but that's only acceptable for very light loads that don't move (like a tiny camera).  Drilling into the brick is going to give you maximum strength.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Even for a very light load moisture in a freezing environment could quickly deteriorate the mortar.

Comment: Yea, thanks, my Texas is showing.  I don't think a lot about freezing, but that's a good point.

Comment: These particular cameras will be in Hardie Plank. How is that strength wise?

Comment: @amrog What's behind the Hardie Plank, regular house sheathing like OSB? If so then just put the screw through both. The Hardie PLank shouldn't be too thick. If so then pre-drill. No need for an anchor.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus no, there isn't anything, it is open space

Comment: @amrog In that case you should look into toggle bolt anchors for the Hardie Planks.